# Cannot change brightness on Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen3

Tags: linux, laptop, xorg, thinkpad, brightness

I bought the `Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen3` with `AMD Ryzen 3 5300u` `APU` recently, I received this laptop yesterday only. I use `ArchLinux` for my `OS` with the `DWM` window manager. This is the first time I am using a `AMD` `CPU` instead of `Intel` one. Most of things are working except the fingerprint scanner.

If I try to change the backlight from terminal using `xbacklight -set 50%` for example I get error saying,

```
No outputs have backlight property
```

I have seen this error before on `Intel` based laptops. To fix this issue on `Intel` laptops I created `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file and added this block of text in the file,

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

What do I have to change here for a `AMD` `CPU`?

There is `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness` which I can edit with `vim` for example, but it won't let me save the file without adding `wq!` but this indeed changes brightness.

I want to be able to change brightness with `xbacklight` as I use a script that displays a notification, changes my status-bar value for brightness and also changes the brightness, that I have binded to the `XF86XK_MonBrightnessUp` and `XF86XK_MonBrightnessDown` receptively for up and down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Backlight#xbacklight) `xbacklight` only works with `Intel` for `AMD/Radeon` I can use something like [acpilight](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/acpilight) which is a "backward-compatibile xbacklight replacement". I also had to [create a `udev`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Backlight#Udev_rule) rule to make the users of `video` group to be able to edit the `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness` file without root access. Now I can change brightness just fine.